# how to flush the buffer to disk period in python

Tags: python, logging, tcp, flush

I write a 'log-server',which is used to receive log from client, using TCP. when receive a log, it will write the log to file on disk. for performance, the file use a large buffer, the problem is the buffer will flush to disk ONLY when buffer is full. So is there any api can make flush perform period?

I have an idea: call the flush in a separate thread period, BUT I'm not sure if it is correct, while another thread may writing data at the same time.

Comment: I don't know if it is the best solution but you can use a lock to only allow one thread access the buffer at a time. Or you can use `asyncio` which will fix this more or less automatically, since everything executes in the same thread.

Comment: I use another thread to flush the bufffer period, everyting works well